# How do I render a pdf in a page using VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, pdf, iframe, embed, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to build a portfolio website for someone and can't manage to render pdfs neither in the webapp nor in a new tab. The pdf files are local, so nothing backend related to access.

`<template> <embed src="/public/pdfs/myPdf.pdf" type="application/pdf" /> </template>`

this sort of code does not work, i have also tried iframes and various modules which were claiming to render pdfs (such as jspdf-dist or VuePDF).

The problem seems to be the fetching of the file. Vue seems to not try to get local files but rather access localhost:port/path/to/files to get them. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put pdf file to `src` folder and import to the component as bellow.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <embed style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh" :src="pdf" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import pdf from "../assets/sample.pdf";
</script>
```

Demo https://gn33f4.csb.app/